# Python - How can I save the player's score as they keep increasing it? Any help is appreciated

Tags: python

to learn Python I'm working on a small terminal upgrade game. The user enters a number that is added to a random integer to get a score (called "Films Produced" in game). The problem I can't seem to fix is every time the player goes to the menu and back then back to entering more numbers the previous number is deleted instead of added on to the new one.

Here is the code:

```
print("TERMINAL FILM by Dominick")
print("---------------------")

# SCORE
def filmClicker():
    global score 
    user_input = int(input(">> Enter a number: "))
    score = user_input

    if user_input > 5 or user_input < 0 or user_input == 0:
        print(">> Not a valid number.")
        filmClicker()
    elif score > 0:
        score = score + random.randint(1, 50) 
        print("")
        print(">> You produced:", score, "films", "<<")

        go_back_or_menu = input(">> Press ENTER to go again. Or type TAB to go back to the menu. ")
        
        if go_back_or_menu == "":
            filmClicker()
        elif go_back_or_menu == "TAB" or "Tab" or "tab": 
            game()


def game():
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Menu >>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(">> Type A to go make films. ")
    print(">> Type B to see your current balance. ")
    print(">> Type C to see the current box office. ")
    print(">> Type D for your stats. ")

    press_button_menu = input("")

    if press_button_menu == "A":
        filmClicker()
    elif press_button_menu == "B":
        print("Current Balance =", score)
        press_enter()
        game()
    else: 
        filmClicker()

game()
```

So I want the player to be able to insert a number, the number gets added to another number by the computer, and then a final number is spit out. I got all that working. But it doesn't save when you do that multiple times. Which I don't want, I want it to stack each time you do it.

Sorry if I poorly explained it, I can answer more about it if needed. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I removed the score = "input" variable and declared it out of any function. But it's still not saving. Here is a better answer as to what I want it to do:

*In the picture below I start at the game menu. I then decide to make films, I do it 5 times. But then when I go back to the menu and check my balance, the balance equals the last time I made films and not the TOTAL films. What I want it to do is add up all of the films. So in this case 48 + 49 + 9 + 38 + 25 instead of having just the last set (which is 25 in this case), to get a total balance which can be displayed by going to the menu and typing "B."*

[image: Picture of program]

*Here is the current code:*

```
import random

score = 0

# SCORE
def filmClicker():
    global score 
    user_input = int(input(">> Enter a number: "))

    if user_input > 5 or user_input < 0 or user_input == 0:
        print(">> Not a valid number.")
        filmClicker()
    elif score > 0:
        score = score + random.randint(1, 50) 
        print("")
        print(">> You produced:", score, "films", "<<")

        go_back_or_menu = input(">> Press ENTER to go again. Or type TAB to go back to the menu. ")
        print(go_back_or_menu)
        
        if go_back_or_menu == "":
            filmClicker()
        elif go_back_or_menu == "TAB" or "Tab" or "tab": 
            game_menu()

# GAME MENU
def game_menu():
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Menu >>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(">> Type A to go make films. ")
    print(">> Type B to see your current balance. ")
    print(">> Type C to see the current box office. ")
    print(">> Type D for your stats. ")

    press_button_menu = input("")

    if press_button_menu == "A":
        filmClicker()
    elif press_button_menu == "B":
        print("Current Balance =", score)
        press_enter()
        game_menu()
    else: 
        filmClicker()

game_menu()
```

**SECOND UPDATE:**

*Updated Code:*

```
import random

score = 0

# PRINT BLANK LINE
def press_enter():
    press_enter = print(input(""))

# SCORE
def filmClicker():
    global score 
    user_input = int(input(">> Enter a number: "))
    score += user_input
    produced = random.randint(1, 50) 

    if user_input > 5 or user_input < 0 or user_input == 0:
        print(">> Not a valid number.")
        filmClicker()
    elif score > 0:
        score += produced
        print("")
        print(">> You produced:", produced, "films", "<<")

        go_back_or_menu = input(">> Press ENTER to go again. Or type TAB to go back to the menu. ")
        print(go_back_or_menu)
        
        if go_back_or_menu == "":
            filmClicker()
        elif go_back_or_menu == "TAB" or "Tab" or "tab": 
            game_menu()


    # GAME MENU
    def game_menu():
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Menu >>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        print(">> Type A to go make films. ")
        print(">> Type B to see your current balance. ")
        print(">> Type C to see the current box office. ")
        print(">> Type D for your stats. ")
    
        press_button_menu = input("")
    
        if press_button_menu == "A":
            filmClicker()
        elif press_button_menu == "B":
            print("Current Balance =", score)
            press_enter()
            game_menu()
        else: 
            filmClicker()
    
    game_menu()
```

In the picture below it's printing how much the player is producing from that turn but I also am testing the score (which is what the 6 and 49 stand for). It's scaling weird like that, where it adds a certain amount after every turn. Any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `+=` operator.

Keep the `score = 0` at the top of the file to initialize the variable, then use `score += user_input` to keep a running tally. This is the same as writing `score = score + user_input`.

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. Thank you so much! I have one last question if that's fine. Is it possible to display the number of films made in a turn but only in that turn? Like when it says "X films produced" after you enter a number, I want it to just display how many films were produces in that certain turn. Right now it keeps stacking each time it says the films produced. So for example, if I a turn, I would want it to just say the films produces in that single turn. NOT in the previous ones. But I could still access the total through the menu.

Comment: @Dominick You can store the random # of films produced in a separate variable `produced = random.randint(1, 50)`, use it in place of the random call `score += produced`, and print `produced` instead of `score`.

Comment: @GeeTransit I seem to have got it but keep getting this weird addition of 4 every time I check the balance. I added the updated code to the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Dominick That's because you are doing `score += user_input` and you were testing with 4 as the input. In the screenshot in the question, it was 2 higher than expected (6 + 41 == 47) because you inputted 2.

Comment: @GeeTransit Ahhhh, alright. Is there any way to not add that input at the end of the turn?

Comment: @Dominick You can remove / comment out that line to not add it. You should also change `elif score > 0:` to `else:` so that it'll run every time user input is correct.

Comment: @GeeTransi Thank you so much for all the help (especially with the very beginner questions).

Answer (score 1):

In your `filmClicker` function, you should remove the following line:

```py
score = user_input
```

By assigning to it, you've essentially erased its previous value which is why it doesn't accumulate between rounds.

Comment: I did that but it's saying "Score is not defined" when I enter a number. What would be a way to solve that?

Comment: @Dominick You can add a `score = 0` at the start of your program (outside any functions) to initialize it and fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

For saving data, You can Use **Files** in python

For Saving:

```
f=open("data_game.txt","w")
f.write(<your score>)
f.close()
```

For Reading:

```
f=open("data_game.txt","r")
score=f.read()
print(score)
f.close()
```